# Update UITableView Data cell From Another View Controller

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, cell, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to update my firstVC "like Button" Status once the user enters the SecondVC and likes or unlikes the heart for the cell they entered. I've tried a ton of different ways today but none seem to work properly. Any help or ideas

Basically. The user can click on a cell, then gets directed to another view controller which they also can change the status of the like button in there. Once they return back to the mainVC I want the like button to display the change.

I'm wondering if I am suppose to save the cells data locally in the phone or just send variables back and forth to each view controller. But if I send variables back and forth, how do I send a variable back to the first VC to the specific cell and let it know that the cell like button is no longer liked. I hope I make sense. Thank you all in advance. Still new to swift here :)

Comment: Think in these terms - MVC. You have the last two pieces, but your `dataSource`(or Model) is *too* "local". I think you "see" this from your question. This is what makes (for me) Combine nice - even without SwiftUI (which I think is too raw still) you are kind of forced to think about your app's Model layer. An app's Model really needs to be more global. I'd recommend putting `dataSource` in `SceneDelegate` if possible or `AppDelegate` otherwise.

Comment: I am kind of seeing what you re trying to say. Is there anyway you can dive deeper for me somehow.

Comment: how can making it global update a UITableView cell

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the delegate pattern

```
protocol ViewController2Delegate: class {
    func buttonStatusDidChange(_ viewController2: ViewController2, to status: Bool)
}
```

Add this property to the second view controller:

```
weak var delegate: ViewController2Delegate?
```

When the button status change, call:

```
delegate?.buttonStatusDidChange(self, to: true)
```

Make the first view controller conform to the protocol:

```
extension ViewController1: ViewController2Delegate {
    func buttonStatusDidChange(_ viewController2: ViewController2, to status: Bool) {
        // change the button according to the status
    }
}
```

Comment: and that will update only the specific cell in the first VC?

Comment: the ViewController is a tableViewController.

Comment: I think so, the first ViewController should know what cell that the second is showing. With the IndexPath property in the first ViewController that stores what cell the second ViewController is displaying.

Comment: Where does the "Make the first view controller conform to the protocol:" code below the go?

Comment: I gave your code a try and it does not change anything. Could you try posting some code